# I'm struggling to do citations in my Latex work [references, bibliography]

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, multiple-citations

Please guys how can I do refrences in my LaTex work, I have TexMaker, Texworks and didn't know how to deal with it. I found some videos on Youtube but they were using Bibdesk to run their bibliography and I do not seem to find this bibdesk app anywhere. a link to a Youtube video will do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about how you intend to create the bibliography: entirely by hand, or with the help of software in the form of one or more LaTeX packages (such as `natbib`, `apacite`, and `biblatex`) and external programs (bibtex, biber)? Should the style of the citation call-outs be numeric, authoryear, or something else? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Some more background information on the type of document you currently write, would also be helpful. Do you write a paper for a specific journal or a thesis using the template from your school/universite/institute? If so, the corrensponding document class/template might already specify one of the package Mico mentioned and might be incompatible with others.

Comment: Yeah, I'm writing a thesis, actually I'm still green in the whole programming world, so I hope you'll sympathize my ignorance and  probably that's why whole bunch of background information were needed. However how can I use these aforementioned packages [natbib,apacite,biblatex] to do my citations. I'm really appreciative of your help guys. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

packages are downloaded on the fly -- you requested for links --

https://libguides.rhul.ac.uk/referencing/latex

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibliography_management_with_bibtex

http://gottscott.github.io/2016/08/30/how-to-do-citations-in-latex.html

Comment: I guess, "packages are downloaded on the fly" refers to OP's question about where to find `BibDesk`. Please be aware that `BibDesk` is *not*  a LaTeX package, but a reference management software (See also: https://bibdesk.sourceforge.io/) and will thus not be downloaded "on the fly".